# Who owns money (EUR) as a thing in the EU?

Tags: european-union, ownership, euro

The European Central Bank prints money (EUR) and puts it into circulation. It is therefore the first owner. Are persons who take possession of the money also owners at the same time? I am talking here about possession and ownership. Or does the ECB remain the owner?

Comment: Are you talking about actual, physical notes and coins or the value of debt they promises to pay?

Comment: @Rick I mean only physical notes and coins. Thx for asking!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### A possessor in good faith owns currency

Currency is owned by the person who has it provided they came into possession legitimately.

Currency is a small category of goods, known as negotiable instruments, where the person who has it, owns it. *Unless*, they came into possession in an illegitimate way, such as by stealing it or finding it (and not handing it in to the authorities). If they received it in the course of a legitimate transaction - wages, payment for goods or services, etc. - then they own it even if the currency was previously tainted. Contrast this with, say, a car, where the legitimate owner remains the legitimate owner no matter who is in possession.

Now, there are usually laws that prohibit the destruction of currency even if you own it, but that doesn’t change the fact that you own it. For comparison, there are laws against dumping your car in the river but it’s still your car.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In Germany, destroying one's money or painting money is not forbidden and is not a criminal offence. In other countries, such as the USA, it is probably a criminal offence.

Comment: @MaikLowrey destroying or *defacing* money is allowed, but *painting money* as in *making copies of mones* is **illegal.**

Comment: What makes a car different? Is it the fact that it has a title? Is a bicycle which doesn’t require registration of title the same? (I suppose it is but the question then is why)

Comment: @Seekinganswers All chattels are the same

Comment: What about civil forfeiture?

Comment: @Acccumulation what about it?